# requesting nasdaq.com using nodejs is failing but working with python

Tags: python, node.js, web-scraping

I was working on a data science project and while doing so I was struggling with a strange issue.

I was scraping this [url](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/aapl) using request-promise-native in nodejs, but it didn't worked. It is strange because every other website is working. When I tried python + requests it worked. What am I doing wrong here? How to implement this using nodejs?

Currently, I am doing this

```js
var options = {uri: url,json:true,headers:req.headers}
              console.log(url)
try{
    var data = await request(options)             
           
}catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: var options = {uri: url,json:true,headers:req.headers} 
                try{var data = await request(options)             

              
              }catch(err){
                console.log(err)
              }